# Consistency of Sample Mean in Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, mean, consistency

I'm looking at page 219 of the book ["Time Series: Theory and Methods" by Brockwell and Davis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441903194), and I can't seem to get my head around one line. Observe that

\begin{align*}
n\text{Var}(\bar{X}) &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i,j=1}^n \text{Cov}(X_i,X_j) \\
&\vdots \\
&= \sum_{|h|<n} \left(1 - \frac{|h|}{n} \right)\gamma(h)\\
&\le \sum_{|h|<n} | \gamma(h)|.
\end{align*}

Using the inequality they say

> If $\gamma(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}$
> $n^{-1} \sum_{|h| < n}|\gamma(h)| = 2\lim_{n \to \infty}|\gamma(n)| =$
> $0$...

Why are those limits equal? I was told it could be showed with Fejer's theorem because it was a Cesaro sum, but wouldn't the book mention this? I am wondering if it's because of something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
n^{-1} \sum_{|h| < n}|\gamma(h)| &= \frac{1}{n}\gamma(0) + \frac{2}{n}\sum_{h=1}^n|\gamma(h)|\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\gamma(0) + \frac{2}{n}\sum_{h=1}^n[h-(h-1)]|\gamma(h)|\\
&\to  0+2\lim_{h \to \infty}|\gamma(h)| \tag{*} \\
&=0.
\end{align*}
The line (*) follows from Cesaro's Lemma, i.e. if $b_n \to \infty$ and $v_n \to v_{\infty}$ then $b_n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - b_{k-1})v_k \to v_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later... here's a solution that does *not* involve invoking Cesaro's Lemma. It follows from the following result:

> If $v_n \to \ell$ as $n \to \infty$, then $\bar{v} := n^{-1}\sum_i v_i \to \ell$ as well.

I just came upon this while doing some exercises in chapter 2 of ["Elements of Large Sample Theory" by E.L. Lehmann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387985956). They ask the same question but give more guidance. There are three questions that sequentially build up to the above result that I asked about in the original post.